# Windows Mobile .net cf

Tags: sql-server, windows, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm working on a project that uses a motorola MC9090 that communicates with a sql database over wifi. I'm having an issue with the battery on the windows mobile device dying very quickly. The windows mobile device is setup to never sleep. I set it this way because I lose my wifi connection when it does. Does anyone know of a way to reconnect to wifi as soon as the windows mobile device wakes up?

Comment: it is a setting in windows phone, you needn't do anything specifically.

Answer (score 2):

You should rewrite your code to be robust against connection lost.

It is a general rule that Mobile device are NOT always connected.

And, there is no setting you can use to let the device re-connect at resume. It does this automatically.

Your issue with the MC9090 is: the Power Management of the device is set so the WiFi is un-powered during suspend.  Possibly Motorola Support can provide you with a reg change to have WiFi also powered in suspend.

The PowerManager knows different states from Full-On to Full-Off with unattended, idle etc in between. The most power is drawn by the Screen backlight. Next comes WiFi when not associated with an AP. Then the other radios (GSM, GPS, Bluetooth) and the barcode scan module.

Normally those industrial devices are designed to last at least a work shift (6-8 hours) with there standard power management settings. Devices for DSD are designed to last even longer (possibly by offering an extended battery).